# Extracting object property as name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have array of objects. Here is small amount of the data:

```
[
  {
    State: "AK",
    AvgExpenseRatio: 0.46,
    Test2: 2,
  },
  {
    State: "AL",
    AvgExpenseRatio: 0.67,
    Test2: 3,
  }]
```

I am checking if the data in Test2 is above 2 and if it is I am returning new object that depends on this data:

```
const temp = mapData.map((el) => {
      return {
        [el.State]: {
          fill: el.Test2 > 2 ? "red" : "green",
        },
      };
    });
```

After this data looks like:

```
[
  0:{
     AK:{
     fill:'green'
     },
  1:{
     AL:{
     fill:'red'
     }
}]
```

I want the final data to look like this:

```
const exampleShouldLook = {
  AK: {
    fill: "green",
          },
  AL: {
    fill: "red"
  }
};
```

Object with object which names are the states. How I can do that. Here is the sandbox example for more clear explain:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sanne-ugmn4?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const mapData = [
  {
    State: "AK",
    AvgExpenseRatio: 0.46,
    Test2: 2,
  },
  {
    State: "AL",
    AvgExpenseRatio: 0.67,
    Test2: 3,
  }]
  
const output = mapData.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val.State] = { fill : val.Test2 > 2 ? "red" : "green" }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```